# C++ references - something is unclear to me

Tags: c++, reference

Please see the following code:

```
int x = 7;
int *p = &x;
int &y = x;

x = 7;
*p = 7;
y = 7;
```

When `x = 42;`

```
x = 42;
*p = 42;
y = 42;
```

When `y = 73;`

```
x = 73;
*p = 73;
y = 73;
```

Why x = 73 ?

Comment: Because `y` is, basically, just an alias for the variable `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many ways, a reference can be seen as an "alias", another name for the same thing, so `x` and `y` are "the same thing, just different names". It obviously doesn't make that much sence to use `y` instead of `x`, but if you have a long and complex thing, such as

```
 person individual;

 if (individual.scores.mathtest[testno] > 75 &&
     individual.scores.mathtest[testno] <= 100)
 {
    individual.scores.mathtest[testno] = 80;
 }
```

then using

```
int &score = individual.scores.mathtest[testno];

if (score > 75 && score <= 100)
{
   score = 80;
}
```

would make for a lot less writing - and it's easier to see that it's the same thing across the whole section of code - rather than trying to spot if there is a difference somewhere in that statement.

If your example, you can see `*p` as another alias. Pointers have slightly different properties than references - for example, you can change what the pointer actually points at. We could add:

```
int z = 8;
p = &z;
```

and now `*p` is no longer an alias to `x`, but an alias to `z`. And if we have:

```
int a[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }
int *p = &a[0];
```

we have `*p` as an alias for element `a[0]` in the array, and we can use

```
p++;
```

to move from `a[0]` to `a[1]`.